# How to access from child to widget in parent window?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have parent class with panel (notebook) and  combobox as follows:

```
class A(wx.aui.AuiMDIChildFrame): 
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.panel_1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.NB = wx.Notebook(self.panel_1, -1, style=0)
        self.NB_A= WindowFirst(self.NB)

        self.ComboA= wx.ComboBox(self.panel_1, 500, 'Phase', (50, 150), (160,-1), phasesList, wx.CB_DROPDOWN)
```

and in another `py` file:

```
class WindowFirst(GeneralPanel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        how do I access ComboA from here?
```

This isn't my complete code... Just want is relevent for the question.

How do I acess `comboA` from `WindowFirst`? I need to be able to set values to the `ComboA` from `WindowFirst`.

I can access from `A` to `WindowFirst`, but not the other way around.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done as long as you are trying to access ComboA from WindowFirst.**init**().  The constructor for WindowFirst is called as NB_A gets created, at which time ComboA has not yet been created.  So no matter how you try to access ComboA, it's not possible because it doesn't exist

However, if you want to access ComboA from another method of WindowFirst, that can be done.  You have NB_A as a child of NB, NB as a child of panel_1, panel_1 as a child of A and ComboA as a child of A.  You just need to make sure ComboA exists before you try to access it.  So something like this.

```
def anotherFunction():
    #how do I access ComboA from here?
    nb = self.GetParent()
    panel_1 = nb.GetParent()
    a = panel_1.GetParent()
    try:
        #try to access ComboA and do what you gotta do
        a.ComboA.doSomething()
    except:
        #something went wrong (like ComboA doesn't exist yet)
        print "ComboA doesn't exist yet"
```

or for brevity

```
def anotherFunction():
    #how do I access ComboA from here?
    try:
        self.GetParent().GetGrandParent().ComboA.doSomething()
    except:
        print "ComboA doesn't exist yet"
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to communicate between classes in wxPython is to use pubsub, which is included with wxPython. Basically you will want to create a listener in your class `A` and then publish messages to it from `WindowFirst` to tell it to update.

Here's an example:

```
import random
import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub

########################################################################
class TabPanel(wx.Panel):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        colors = ["red", "blue", "gray", "yellow", "green"]
        self.color = random.choice(colors)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(self.color)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.update_button)

        lbox = wx.ListBox(self, choices=colors)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(lbox, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def update_button(self, event):
        """"""
        pub.sendMessage('button_listener', message=self.color)

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)


########################################################################
class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    Frame that holds all other widgets
    """

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                          "Notebook Tutorial",
                          size=(600,400)
                          )
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.tab_num = 3

        self.notebook = wx.Notebook(panel)
        tabOne = TabPanel(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.AddPage(tabOne, "Tab 1")

        tabTwo = TabPanel(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.AddPage(tabTwo, "Tab 2")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Get Color")
        sizer.Add(self.btn)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()

        # create a listener
        pub.subscribe(self.change_button, 'button_listener')

        self.Show()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def change_button(self, message, arg2=None):
        """"""
        self.btn.SetLabel(message)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = DemoFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note that the pubsub API changed slightly in wxPython 2.9 and above. If you're using an older version, then you'll need to change the code a bit. I have a tutorial illustrating the older API [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/).

For more information on the newer API, check out my updated article here:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/09/05/wxpython-2-9-and-the-newer-pubsub-api-a-simple-tutorial/